# RegEx replace multiple groups in 1 action

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a string of numbers that looks similar to this

```
01234567890
01234567890
01234567890
01234567890
01234567890
01234567890
```

What I want is to separate that group into batches while also making each batch single line separated by comma so the final output would look like this:

```
01234567890,01234567890,01234567890,01234567890

01234567890,01234567890,01234567890,01234567890

01234567890,01234567890,01234567890,01234567890
```

I have 2 RegEx each doing one task or the other, but I'm wondering if there's a way to combine them?

```
(\d{11})\n  and   $1, - to replace
```

That will put it all into 1 line separated by a comma and the 2nd RegEx that will put them into batches of however many I want "x"

```
((\d{11})\n){x}  and   $0\n\n\n - to replace
```

Putting the 2 replace expressions next to each other doesn't provide the result that I want. So I wonder if it's even possible to combine the 2 actions or do they have to be separate?

Comment: Just curious.. Which language are you using?

Comment: Is it in Notepad++? Try `^(\d{11})\R(\d{11})\R(\d{11})\R(\d{11})$` and replace with `$1,$2,$3,$4`

Comment: Mainly Javascript, but I'm wondering just in general
I use VSCode for most of my scripting and sometimes have to convert strings for use with my script that I run. VScode has a handy Search and Replace function that allows RegEx, so while doing what Wiktor suggested is possible it becomes impractical if I need say batches of 50 in a line separated by a comma